# C/C++ Common Controls detecting double-click of TVItem

Tags: c++, c, winapi, treeview, common-controls

Is there any way to detect if a tree view control (and specifically a TVITEM) is double clicked using Common Controls & WINAPI?
I mean in my wndproc function of a form.

If so, what are the msg, wParam & lParam in that case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A treeview control sends an [`NM_DBLCLK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-dblclk-tree-view) notification when you double-click it, with  `uMsg` = `WM_NOTIFY` and `lParam` pointing to an `NMHDR` structure as per the documentation.

You can then send the treeview control a [`TVM_HITTEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tvm-hittest) message to determine the item under the cursor, something like:

```
TVHITTESTINFO tvhti = {};
GetCursorPos (&tvhti.pt);
ScreenToClient (hTreeView, &tvhti.pt);
SendMessage (hTreeView, TVM_HITTEST, 0, (LPARAM) &tvhti);
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-tvhittestinfo) for the values returned by `TVM_HITTEST`.